# Keep a socket server listening permanently?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I'm very new to socket programming, so please excuse me if this is a dumb question. I've written a socket server in PHP so I can connect my iOS app (Swift) and receive data in real-time.

I managed to follow some tutorials and write a basic example script, but the only thing I'm not quiet getting yet is how to activate the socket server. In every tutorial, I'm reading about using Terminal (Mac) or Command Prompt (Windows) to launch a socket server in order to connect a client to it. Is this just for testing purposes or this an actual step in setting up a server for permanent use?

I'm still trying to figure out how I would run a socket server and just keep it running on my webhost permanently so users of my can connect and disconnect to the socket 24/7 (permanently). I don't understand why a socket server that can be connected to by clients all around the world would have to run on my PC.

I'm used to writing PHP scripts for data storage and retrieval, and I would just run those scripts on my webhost, so that's why it seems weird to me that you suddenly need to run PHP code from a local PC instead of an online host. Can someone explain to me how to activate a socket server and keep it listening for client connections permanently?

Comment: while possible, php is poorly designed for persistent operations. "php daemon" is what you want to google

Answer (score 0):

A web server is simply another computer. You can run a PHP script on it to serve sockets just as you do on a local computer, assuming you have the permissions.

Also, websockets are a special case of sockets. If you don't know if you are using websockets, then you are not using them.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is a lot of confusion in the terms you are referring to, here is a quick overview of a web stack:

1. A server, which can be any regular PC.
2. A way for clients to send you requests, popular stacks include a web server (nginx, apache), an interface bewteen the server and scripts (uwsgi, fastcgi) and applications that serve content (python,php).
3. Clients that want to consume or post information.

> Is this just for testing purposes or this an actual step in setting up
>   a server for permanent use?

It might as well be used permanently, however it's absolutely NOT recommended to use your testing tools in production.

> Can someone explain to me how to activate a socket server and keep it
>   listening for client connections permanently?

In order to serve content "online" you must have either a VPS (like linode or digitalocean) or a way to make your computer available to the internet (using DDNS or directly using your public IP)

What you refer to as "suddenly need to run PHP code from a local PC instead of an online host" is relative to who is the client and who is the server, in your case your PC is both, your client just asks for information to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! So from the 3 components of the web stack you posted, I understand that a PC is absolutely necessary for a running web socket connection, is that correct? I have my own domain hosted online and it has a server IP address, but is it not possible to use this server to run my web socket on (I have to provide an IP and a port number to initialize my web socket object)? If it IS possible, where would I leave the script and how would I connect to it?

Comment: I used to do this on a Windows PC by keeping the file on a local directory and use CMD command line `server server.php` to connect to it. Can I also upload the `server.php` file to my webhost file manager like all the other PHP scripts (for storage and retrieval) or would it be impossible to connect to it if I did that?

Comment: You have to check the availability with your hosting service, it is very common that hosting services do NOT provide the common tools to run full-fledged apps like the one you describe, only simple scripts to support webpages and common web services like wordpress, joomla, etc. For that you will probably need a VPS service like Linode.